# How to map Spanner Change Data Capture column names to different column names in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner, change-data-capture

I have created the change data capture (CDC) of a Spanner database table, but the problem is that in the BigQuery table, the column names are different, causing the data flow pipeline to fail. How do I map the CDC column names to the different column names of the BigQuery table? I have not found an existing template where we can perform this mapping successfully.

I have tried the query below, but none of them worked. Is there any way to solve this problem with existing template

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template run sku-inv-loc-bq-dataflow --template-file-gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates-us-central1/latest/flex/Spanner_Change_Streams_to_BigQuery --region us-central1 --subnetwork https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/npd-met/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/mit-dfe-np-us-central1 --network mit-dfd-vpc --parameters spannerInstanceId=us-central-sku-location1-qacd,spannerDatabase=sku-location1-db-qacd,spannerMetadataInstanceId=us-central-sku-location1-qacd,spannerMetadataDatabase=sku-location1-db-qacd,spannerChangeStreamName=sku_inv_loc_change_stream,bigQueryDataset=sku_inv_loc_db2b
```